# Substantif pour « action de devenir », apparenté à « venue » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Existe-t-il un mot du même genre que "venue", dans le sens

> J'attends impatiemment la venue de mon ami.

mais calqué sur le verbe "devenir" ?

En somme, un nom commun signifiant "le fait de devenir" et se trouvant de fait dans le même champ lexical que "le changement", "la modification", "le remplacement par qqch.", etc.

Answer (score 3):

L'infinitif à une double... *vocation*... :-)
Dont... celle de substantif.

Le fait de devenir ? Eh bien ce n'est rien d'autre que ***le devenir***.

Nota : Ça peut se mettre au pluriel, mais c'est rare dans la mesure où, devenu substantif, le verbe conserve quand même le coté généralisateur, *chose-en-soi*, de l'infinitif.
Ainsi préférera-t-on certainement écrire sur :

- *le devenir des choses* que sur
- *les devenirs des choses*

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il existe et c'est tout simplement « devenir ». Vous trouverez beaucoup d'information sur ce mot [ici](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+venue%2Cle+devenir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20venue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20devenir%3B%2Cc0) (devenir³). Vous devriez savoir cependant que c'est un mot beaucoup moins courant que « venue » et il faut faire attention en l'utilisant ; il faut vérifier dans un dictionnaire chaque usage que l'on a en tête jusqu'à ce que l'on  soit familier avec eux, cela pour s'assurer que l'emploi est idiomatique. C'est un mot plutôt philosophique.

Answer (score 1):

D'une façon générique on pourrait l'exprimer ainsi :

> J'attends nos retrouvailles avec impatience.

Dans cette formulation, l'impatience caractérise plus les retrouvailles que l'attente.